# enumitem and horizontal spacing

Tags: spacing, enumitem

Is there an easy way to use item label as if they were typed directly in the code (see the 2nd formatting in my MWE)? If it is not the case, I will use another way to acheive my goal.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand\recproof[1]{
    \bfseries
    \ifnum#1=1
        Initialization.
    \else
        \ifnum#1=2
            Heredity.
        \else
            Conclusion.
        \fi
    \fi
}

\setlength\parindent{0cm}


\begin{document}

Bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla...

\begin{enumerate}[label=\protect\recproof{\value*}]
    \item $n = 0$, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla...

    \item $n \Rightarrow n + 1$, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla...

    \item $\forall n$, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla...
\end{enumerate}

Bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla...

\textbf{Initialization.} $n = 0$, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla...

\textbf{Heredity.} $n \Rightarrow n + 1$, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla...

\textbf{Conclusion.} $\forall n$, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla...

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `wide=0pt`.

You also want less clumsy code.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\recprooflabel}{m}
 {
  \int_case:nnF { #1 }
   {
    {1}{Initialization}
    {2}{Heredity}
    {3}{Conclusion}
   }
   {????}   % Some error to raise here?
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentEnvironment{recproof}{O{}}
 {\begin{enumerate}[label=\bfseries\recprooflabel{\value*}.,wide=0pt,#1]}
 {\end{enumerate}}
 

\begin{document}

Bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, 
bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, 
bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, 
bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, 
bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla...

\begin{recproof}
  \item $n = 0$, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, 
  bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla...

  \item $n \Rightarrow n + 1$, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, 
  bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla...

  \item $\forall n$, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, 
  bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla...
\end{recproof}

Bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, 
bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, 
bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, 
bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, 
bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla...

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `recproof` environment has an optional argument for additional `enumitem` keys.

Comment: Thanks for the customized environment, and the cleaner code. I didn't read the whole doc of `enumitem`, I plead guilty about the `wide` option. Thanks for that!